# Dimple.js assign colour to bar, when series is null

Tags: d3.js, charts, visualization, dimple.js

I'm trying to change the default colour in Dimple.js, I want each bar to be red, I can change the colour by individually citing each entry in the series, but I can't seem to change the colour across the whole chart, once I set the buyerchartSeries to null.

```
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg2_3, data);
    myChart.setBounds(10, 15, "92%", "84%");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "sum");
    var y = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "service");
    y.addOrderRule("sum");
    y.hidden = true;
    var buyerchartSeries = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar); 
    myChart.assignColor(null,"red")

    myChart.draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is fine but if you also have some non-null series identifiers which you would like to colour separately it won't work.  You can use assignColor but you need to assign to "All":

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg2_3, data);
myChart.setBounds(10, 15, "92%", "84%");
myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "sum");
var y = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "service");
y.addOrderRule("sum");
y.hidden = true;
var buyerchartSeries = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar); 

// This is all I've changed
myChart.assignColor("All", "red");

myChart.draw();
```

Comment: John, thanks for that, that feels like a more appropriate way of handling the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer... it might be an egregious hack, or it might be the best way to do this, (advice welcome).

Rather than assign a colour to a 'null' series, which obviously won't work, I've changed the defaultColor of the chart. If you only have one colour it has the correct effect of imposing a single colour on all the bars.

```
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg3_1, dt);
    myChart.setBounds(4, 20, "88%", "80%");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "sum");
    var y = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y", "supplier");
    y.hidden = true;
    supplierChartSeries = myChart.addSeries("supplier", dimple.plot.bar);

    myChart.defaultColors = [
      new dimple.color("#3498db", "#2980b9", 1), // blue
    ];
```